# How to sort objects by field value?

Tags: java

If I have a ArrayList of Columns and Columns have the field disparityRating which is an int how do I sort the arraylist of column by the value of the disparityRating field?

I have tried implementing the comparable interface on my column class but when I do and change the compare to parameter to Column like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Column o) {
    return 0;
}
```

It comes up with an error saying method does not override method from its superclass

My main class has an arraylist of columns

```
Collection<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();
```

and so I want to be able to sort them by using

```
Collections.sort(columns);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "implements Comparable".

```
public class ... extends ... implements Comparable<Column> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Column o) {
       return Integer.compare(disparityRating, o.disparityRating);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks but then what do I run in main because Collections.sort(columns); doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, no worries now i've sorted it.

Comment: Needed to change Collection<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();
to ArrayList<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Glad you found it.  Please consider the answer below using Comparator for when the sort criteria are not the "natural ordering" of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could :

```
 Collections.sort(ListOfCols, new Comparator<Column>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Column o1,Column o2) {
                       return o2.getRating().compareTo(o1.getRating());
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Yes, this is useful when ordering by something that doesn't represent the "natural ordering" of the objects.